# contact form select option debends on other select option

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

How I can create contact form where is multiple select options

Example:

```
Select option: Products | Construction
```

and if user selects `Construction` then will show new drop down where he can select:

```
Select option: Roof | Walls | Foundation
```

or if user selects products then it will not show this select option `roof, walls, foundation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try plugin: [Contact Form 7 – Conditional Fields.](https://vi.wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/)
It can help you solve questions.